# How to combine in one condition HAVING and AND in Oracle

Tags: oracle, conditional-statements, having

I wonder how can I put in one condition having and for example:

```
select count(s.id) from card c
                  join subject s on c.ean=s.ean
                  join account a on s.id=a.owner_subject
                 where a.status_external=0
                   and a.status_internal=0
                   and s.type=0
having( 
( trunc(max(s.hist_modified_tmsp))<=last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)) and level=1 )  
or  
( trunc(min(s.hist_modified_tmsp))<=last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)) and level=2 ) )
```

My Oracle tells me "Not a GROUP BY Expression". Any ideas please?
I will be very grateful for any help,
thank you

Comment: Where's your expression for condition_01 and condition_02? Are you testing them for something?

Comment: they are not important here, I just wrote something to looks more like real example

Comment: Well, how do you know they're not the problem for your missing expression?

Comment: They are not. They are just another ones conditions, and the code works fine without the last and which I need to have

Comment: I can put here my real code, but I think it would be just more messy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Having` begins a clause similar to `where` (except applied after aggregation (e.g. sums) instead of before), so you can only have it once in the query like this:

```
having ((sum(col)<=30 and type=4) or (sum(col)>=30 and type=5))
```

Also you need a `group by` clause specifying the columns that the query groups by:

```
group by type, ...
```

Comment: @tony_andrews Hi, thank you, sounds logicly, but I tried that and my Oracle says "not a GROUP BY expression" in place where type=4 starts. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Yte, update your post to contain your new query you are using.

Comment: @ mmmmmpie ok, it will be possibly more confusing, but maybe I'm just underestimating you guys :)

Comment: Your query needs to have a `GROUP BY` clause and that needs to include `type`.

Comment: @TonyAndrews
Hi, thank you! It work's! Finally! :) 
But, why I have to have there a `group by` clause? 
It's because of the `having` clause? Kindly please be tolerant to my trivial questions, I'm new in SQL, thank you very much :)

Comment: It's a strange (to me) rule in SQL that if you are writing a query that aggregates data (i.e. uses SUM, COUNT, AVG etc.) then you must  list in a GROUP BY clause all columns that are *not* aggregates e.g. `select deptno, count(*) from emp group by deptno;`.  However if there are no non-aggregated columns then you don't need GROUP BY: `select count(*) from emp;`. HAVING clause is optional and can be used with or without GROUP BY